# Change css of a div when focused

Tags: javascript

I change the css of a div at the moment of focus in an input. But i would like to cancel the value of the focus when i enter a letter in the input.

So how to render the initial css of my div when i enter a value in the input ?

**I created a snippet for ease.**

```js
function setFocused() {
      var results = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
      for (result of results) {
        result.classList.add('focused');
      }
    }

    function unsetFocused() {
      var results = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
      for (result of results) {
        result.classList.remove('focused');
      }
    }

    var results = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
    for (result of results) {
      result.addEventListener("focus", setFocused);
      result.addEventListener("blur", unsetFocused);
    }
```

```css
.test.focused {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
    <div class="test">
        Hello
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can add a eventListener for the input (typing). On that function you can remove the classes.

I hope this will solve the issue. Please find the below code.

```js
function setFocused() {
      var results = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
      for (result of results) {
        result.classList.add('focused');
      }
    }

    function unsetFocused() {
      var results = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
      for (result of results) {
        result.classList.remove('focused');
      }
    }
    
    function onChange(){
            var results = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
              result.classList.remove('test','focused');

    }

    var results = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
    for (result of results) {
      result.addEventListener("focus", setFocused);
      result.addEventListener("blur", unsetFocused);
      result.addEventListener("input", onChange);
    }
```

```css
.test.focused {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
    <div class="test">
        Hello
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but when i write and then i delete. My div do not become red again.